# How to keep react modal open when the popup window is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to React js. After a series of youtube videos, I am working on a project.

My project searches for recipes with some keywords. I am trying to add a filter to filter out some recipes with a react modal. I know I can create a popup with React modal but not sure if this is the best way to have a popup.

Here's a screenshot of my filter popup:
[image]

The problem I'm having now is when I clicked on the input bar, the window closed.

Here's the modal component:

```
class Filter extends Component {
render() {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
          <div className="background"
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '0',
              bottom: '0',
              left: '0',
              right: '0',
              display: 'grid',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            }}
            onClick={this.props.onClose}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                padding: 20,
                background: '#fff',
                borderRadius: '2px',
                display: 'inline-block',
                minHeight: '300px',
                margin: '1rem',
                position: 'relative',
                minWidth: '300px',
                boxShadow: '0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23)',
                justifySelf: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <form className="filter-form">  
                <div>
                    <p>Max Calories: </p>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.props.handler}></input>
                </div>
              </form>
              <hr />
              <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>,
          document.getElementById('filter-popup')
        )
      }
}
```

Please let me know if other code is needed.

Comment: The problem is because of `onClick={this.props.onClose}` on `<div className="background"`? So do you want to close if you click anywhere on the modal?

Comment: I don't want the modal to close if the user clicked anywhere on the modal. Other than the close button.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nithish! This worked.

Comment: Then removing `onClick={this.props.onClose}` from `<div className="background">` should help.